# Get list of items with wikipedia in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, wikipedia

I was trying to create list of all the iPhone models out of wikipedia using urllib and re.
I am able to get a list with all the iPhones but there is a lot of garbage and characters that I don't want.
Is there any other way to delimit the characters.

Notice the pattern in each of the iPhone models. They all have a space and a parenthesis followed by the number 2. [See link provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMldi.jpg) 
Is there any way I could use this as a separator to my advantage?

```
import re
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone#Models'

req = urllib.request.Request(url)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

resp_data = resp.read()

paragraphs = str((re.findall('(iPhone ..............)', str(resp_data))))

print(paragraphs)
```

I also tried writing the list to a .txt file and maybe working my way around there.

```
import re
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone#Models'

req = urllib.request.Request(url)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

resp_data = resp.read()

paragraphs = str((re.findall('(iPhone ..........)', str(resp_data))))

#print(paragraphs)

# Create a new .txt file and copy the contents of paragraphs to it.
iphone_list = open("iphone_list", "w+")
iphone_list.write(paragraphs)
#This down here doens't work somehow I don't know why
iphone_list.read().replace(",", "\n")
iphone_list.close()
```

Now this is what happens:

```
Output I want:
['iPhone', 'iPhone 3G', iPhone 3GS', iPhone 4, iphone 4S, etc]



Output I get: 
['iPhone - Wikipedia</t', 'iPhone 11 Pro Max</a>', 'iPhone 7 and up)</li>', 'iPhone 7 and up)</li>', 'iPhone models</a></td', "iPhone use Apple\\'s <", 'iPhone has <a href="/', 'iPhone can <a href="/', 'iPhone 3GS</a>. Other', 'iPhone models, each a', 'iPhone 3G</a> added <', 'iPhone 3GS</a> with i', 'iPhone 4</a> with a m', 'iPhone 4S</a> with im', 'iPhone 5</a> featured', 'iPhone 5S</a> with im', 'iPhone 5C</a>, a vers', 'iPhone 6 and iPhone 6', 'iPhone 6S</a> was int', 'iPhone SE</a>\\xe2\\x80', 'iPhone 7 and iPhone 7', 'iPhone 8 and iPhone 8', 'iPhone X</a> was rele', 'iPhone 8 and iPhone 8', 'iPhone XS</a>, an upg', 'iPhone X, <a href="/w', 'iPhone XS Max</a>, a ', 'iPhone XR</a>, a lowe', 'iPhone X.\\n</p><p>The', 'iPhone was described ', 'iPhone have also garn', 'iPhone is one of the ', 'iPhone Upgrade Progra', 'iPhone OS 1.0</a>\\n</', 'iPhone OS 3.1.3</a>\\n', 'iPhone 3G</a></b>\\n</', 'iPhone OS 2.0</a>\\n</', 'iPhone 3GS</a></b>\\n<', 'iPhone OS 3.0</a>\\n</', 'iPhone 4</a></b>\\n</t', 'iPhone 4S</a></b>\\n</', 'iPhone 5</a></b>\\n</t', 'iPhone 5C</a></b>\\n</', 'iPhone 5S</a></b>\\n</', 'iPhone 6 / 6 Plus</a>', 'iPhone 6S / 6S Plus</', 'iPhone SE</a></b>\\n</', 'iPhone 7 / 7 Plus</a>', 'iPhone 8 / 8 Plus</a>', 'iPhone X</a></b>\\n</t', 'iPhone XS / XS Max</a', 'iPhone XR</a></b>\\n</', 'iPhone 11</a></b>\\n</', 'iPhone 11 Pro/11 Pro ', 'iPhone is discontinue', 'iPhone began in 2004,', 'iPhone 3G),<sup id="c', 'iPhone to the public ', 'iPhone resulted in se', 'iPhone was made avail', 'iPhone availability:<', 'iPhone available sinc', 'iPhone available sinc', 'iPhone 3G</div><div c', 'iPhone 3G in twenty-t', 'iPhone 3G in upwards ', 'iPhone 3GS on June 8,', 'iPhone was made of al', 'iPhone 3G and 3GS fea', 'iPhone 3G was availab', 'iPhone 3GS was availa', 'iPhone 4 has an <a hr', 'iPhone 4 reported dro', 'iPhone 4</a>. Verizon', 'iPhone accounted for ', 'iPhone <a href="/wiki', 'iPhone in the US.<sup', 'iPhone 4S</a>. Over 1', 'iPhone being manufact', 'iPhone 4S on October ', 'iPhone 4S was estimat', 'iPhone assembly line ', 'iPhone 5. It has a 4-', 'iPhone 4 and 4S. The ', 'iPhone 5 has the <a h', "iPhone 4S\\' A5 and is", 'iPhone 4S, measuring ', 'iPhone with LTE Advan', 'iPhone and iPad. "App', 'iPhone models during ', 'iPhone 5C, a mid-rang', 'iPhone 5S comes in th', 'iPhone 6 and the iPho', 'iPhone 7 and 7 Plus</', 'iPhone 8 and 8 Plus, ', 'iPhone X, which featu', 'iPhone XS, XS Max<sup', 'iPhone XS and XS Max ', 'iPhone XR retained th', 'iPhone X and also fea', "iPhone XS/XS Max\\'s I", 'iPhone 11 at <a href=', 'iPhone 11 Pro and the', 'iPhone 11 Pro Max.<su', 'iPhone units over fiv', 'iPhone had a market s', 'iPhone sales volume a', 'iPhone 4S</a>, Apple ', 'iPhone 4S in parts of', 'iPhone 4S was dominan', 'iPhone alone (at $22.', 'iPhone 5</a> and <a h', 'iPhone 4S</a> were th', "iPhone portfolio\\'s p", 'iPhone line has still', 'iPhone despite growin', 'iPhone trade-in progr', 'iPhone 5S and 5C mode', 'iPhone 5S by an addit', 'iPhone access to over', 'iPhone Upgrade Progra', 'iPhone Upgrade Progra', 'iPhone every year, wi', 'iPhone they have over', 'iPhone after 12 month', 'iPhone with a new one', 'iPhone hardware; cell', 'iPhone users are disp', 'iPhone fundamentally ', 'iPhone OS</a> (rename', 'iPhone 4</a>, all iPh', 'iPhone 4s</a> in 2012', 'iPhone 5C</a> line in', 'iPhone 6</a> devices ', 'iPhone 5</a> is four ', 'iPhone 4</a> and <a h', 'iPhone 4S</a> have a ', 'iPhone 4, the technol', "iPhone 5 model\\'s scr", 'iPhone X</a> is the f', 'iPhone to use an <a h', 'iPhone 5S, externally', 'iPhone 5. From left t', 'iPhone are based on t', 'iPhone 3GS and later ', 'iPhone 6S and 6 plus ', 'iPhone has a minimal ', 'iPhone X</a> and late', 'iPhone 4 has two sepa', 'iPhone and metal on a', 'iPhone to use cell to', 'iPhone 3G generation,', 'iPhone employs <a hre', 'iPhone 4S generation ', 'iPhone 8 it supports ', 'iPhone 6S and 6S Plus', 'iPhone SE and iPhone ', 'iPhone XR. Haptic tou', 'iPhone does not rotat', 'iPhone 5S, this funct', 'iPhone 3GS, which is ', 'iPhone 3GS, the iPhon', "iPhone 4, Apple\\'s sm", 'iPhone models contain', 'iPhone (starting with', 'iPhone 7), however, d', 'iPhone models startin', 'iPhone 5S</a> (exclud', 'iPhone 5C</a>) featur', 'iPhone 6</a>) using <', 'iPhone X</a>.\\n</p>\\n', 'iPhone 6</a> and late', 'iPhone SE</a>), a <a ', 'iPhone X</a>, a <a hr', 'iPhone 5S.</div></div', 'iPhone 4 includes an ', 'iPhone models and as ', 'iPhone is recessed in', 'iPhone while driving ', 'iPhone 7 and later ha', 'iPhone by <a href="/w', 'iPhone 7 up until iPh', 'iPhone also include t', 'iPhone does not offic', 'iPhone users from exc', 'iPhone 4 also support', 'iPhone did not suppor', 'iPhone unit and expos', 'iPhone features an in', 'iPhone can be charged', 'iPhone support wirele', 'iPhone has been criti', 'iPhone 3G its lowest ', 'iPhone battery replac', 'iPhone has been <a hr', 'iPhone 3G uses a diff', 'iPhone X features a d', 'iPhone battery system', 'iPhone models slowing', 'iPhone 4 is the first', 'iPhone 4 and subseque', 'iPhone and iPhone 3G ', 'iPhone and iPhone 3G ', 'iPhone OS 2.0 introdu', 'iPhone 3GS has a 3.2-', 'iPhone and directly u', 'iPhone 4 introduced a', 'iPhone that can nativ', 'iPhone 4 also has a s', "iPhone 4S\\' camera ca", 'iPhone 5</a> and <a h', 'iPhone 4S</a>, runnin', 'iPhone 5</a> can also', 'iPhone 5</a> reported', 'iPhone 5S features Tr', 'iPhone 6 and 6 Plus i', 'iPhone 4S and later m', 'iPhone 6S and 6S Plus', 'iPhone SE features th', 'iPhone 6S and iPhone ', 'iPhone 7 features opt', 'iPhone to feature dua', 'iPhone 7 Plus is a <a', 'iPhone 8 camera remai', 'iPhone X camera is al', "iPhone 8\\'s camera, b", 'iPhone XS, XS Max and', 'iPhone 11, 11 Pro and', 'iPhone was initially ', 'iPhone 3G was availab', 'iPhone 3GS came in 16', 'iPhone 4 was availabl', 'iPhone 4S at a reduce', 'iPhone 4S was availab', 'iPhone 5 and 5S were ', 'iPhone 4S: 16, 32, an', 'iPhone 5C model was i', 'iPhone 6 and 6S were ', 'iPhone SE was availab', 'iPhone 7 and 7 Plus w', 'iPhone 7 and 7 Plus h', 'iPhone 6S and 6S Plus', 'iPhone SE six months ', 'iPhone 8, 8 Plus, and', 'iPhone XS and XS Max ', 'iPhone XR comes in th', 'iPhone 5S with the SI', 'iPhone use a <a href=', 'iPhone 3G and 3GS in ', 'iPhone models shipped', 'iPhone is usually sol', 'iPhone from being use', 'iPhone 4 features a <', 'iPhone 4, just the sa', 'iPhone 4S activated o', 'iPhone 4S usually has', 'iPhone 4S for use on ', 'iPhone 4S that has be', 'iPhone 5 and later iP', 'iPhone XS, XS Max and', 'iPhone 3G and later m', 'iPhone 4. From left t', 'iPhone 4 in plastic h', 'iPhone models</a> inc', 'iPhone includes a ste', 'iPhone <a href="/wiki', 'iPhone <a href="/wiki', 'iPhone versions).<sup', 'iPhone 3G and 3GS are', 'iPhone to charge from', 'iPhone 3G and iPhone ', 'iPhone 6</a>, Apple a', 'iPhone X and later), ', 'iPhone models have a ', 'iPhone models before ', 'iPhone 4S use eccentr', 'iPhone 4S uses a line', 'iPhone 5, 5C, and 5S ', 'iPhone 6 and 6 Plus u', 'iPhone 6S and after u', 'iPhone runs an <a hre', 'iPhone OS).<sup id="c', 'iPhone 3GS, <a href="', 'iPhone comes with a s', 'iPhone either wireles', 'iPhone applications n', 'iPhone 4, a primitive', 'iPhone 8 and earlier.', 'iPhone X and later mo', 'iPhone contained the ', 'iPhone 3GS and iPhone', 'iPhone users can rear', 'iPhone 5</a>, <a href', 'iPhone 6</a> and late', 'iPhone models support', 'iPhone presents a num', 'iPhone allows audio <', 'iPhone functions. For', 'iPhone is brought clo', 'iPhone does not suppo', 'iPhone 4 supports vid', 'iPhone 3GS, allows us', 'iPhone will dial it.<', 'iPhone includes a <a ', 'iPhone can sort its m', 'iPhone uses a large f', 'iPhone 3GS, the volum', 'iPhone supports <a hr', 'iPhone can play <a hr', 'iPhone allows users t', 'iPhone includes softw', 'iPhone <a href="/wiki', 'iPhone is connected t', 'iPhone 3G introduced ', 'iPhone 4S introduced ', 'iPhone 3GS.<sup id="c', 'iPhone models include', 'iPhone as of 2019. \\n', 'iPhone will ask to jo', 'iPhone will automatic', 'iPhone 3G and onwards', 'iPhone 3G onwards) ca', 'iPhone does not suppo', 'iPhone was introduced', 'iPhone could access "', 'iPhone (and <a href="', 'iPhone supports <a hr', 'iPhone 3GS and iPhone', 'iPhone users can and ', 'iPhone generated 50 t', 'iPhone customer is mo', 'iPhone users use data', 'iPhone 3G and iPhone ', 'iPhone in January 201', 'iPhone 6 and 6 Plus w', 'iPhone <a href="/wiki', 'iPhone implements a <', 'iPhone 4S and above, ', 'iPhone also features ', 'iPhone firmware, this', 'iPhone 2.0 firmware.<', 'iPhone will sync emai', 'iPhone has built-in s', 'iPhone would support ', 'iPhone interface.<sup', 'iPhone SDK was offici', 'iPhone and iPod Touch', 'iPhone simulator". Ho', 'iPhone users; owners ', 'iPhone to have: In 20', 'iPhone users to downl', 'iPhone claiming it du', 'iPhone to a laptop or', 'iPhone later globally', 'iPhone outside of the', 'iPhone has been descr', 'iPhone attracts users', 'iPhone has also been ', 'iPhone 4S, Apple adde', 'iPhone with <a href="', 'iPhone Hearing Aids.<', 'iPhone hearing aids a', 'iPhone acts as a remo', 'iPhone hearing aid. L', 'iPhone 3GS, <a href="', 'iPhone lets the user ', 'iPhone can enlarge te', 'iPhone 3GS also featu', 'iPhone is placed in a', 'iPhone models have be', 'iPhone 8</a> (2017\\xe', 'iPhone 8 Plus</a> (20', 'iPhone XR</a> (2018\\x', 'iPhone 11</a></b> (20', 'iPhone 11 Pro</a></b>', 'iPhone 11 Pro Max</a>', 'iPhone 3G</a> (2008\\x', 'iPhone 3GS</a> (2009\\', 'iPhone 4</a> (2010\\xe', 'iPhone 4S</a> (2011\\x', 'iPhone 5</a> (2012\\xe', 'iPhone 5C</a> (2013\\x', 'iPhone 5S</a> (2013\\x', 'iPhone 6</a> (2014\\xe', 'iPhone 6 Plus</a> (20', 'iPhone 6S</a> (2015\\x', 'iPhone 6S Plus</a> (2', 'iPhone SE</a> (2016\\x', 'iPhone 7</a> (2016\\xe', 'iPhone 7 Plus</a> (20', 'iPhone X</a> (2017\\xe', 'iPhone XS</a> (2018\\x', 'iPhone XS Max</a> (20', 'iPhone 11 Pro" alt="i', 'iPhone 11" alt="iPhon', 'iPhone XR" alt="iPhon', 'iPhone XS" alt="iPhon', 'iPhone X" alt="iPhone', 'iPhone 8" alt="iPhone', 'iPhone 7" alt="iPhone', 'iPhone 6S" alt="iPhon', 'iPhone 6" alt="iPhone', 'iPhone SE" alt="iPhon', 'iPhone 5S" alt="iPhon', 'iPhone 5C" alt="iPhon', 'iPhone 5" alt="iPhone', 'iPhone 4S" alt="iPhon', 'iPhone 4" alt="iPhone', 'iPhone 3GS" alt="iPho', 'iPhone 3G" alt="iPhon', 'iPhone (1st generatio', 'iPhone (1st generatio', 'iPhone was copied fro', 'iPhone has also inspi', 'iPhone trademark.<sup', 'iPhone since 2004.<su', 'iPhone in June 2007, ', 'iPhone initial releas', 'iPhone and <a href="/', 'iPhone and other iOS ', "iPhone user\\'s moveme", 'iPhone that "Apple an', 'iPhone for making loc', 'iPhone 4) which reduc', 'iPhone a "national se', 'iPhone Locks Out N.S.', 'iPhone contents.<sup ', 'iPhone 5C</a> that wa', 'iPhone users.<sup id=', 'iPhone had been chang', 'iPhone have made comp', 'iPhone to be used on ', 'iPhone normally preve', 'iPhone 3G must be act', 'iPhone 3G more diffic', 'iPhone and <a href="/', 'iPhone OS 2.0, caused', 'iPhone 3G and iPhone ', 'iPhone 3G and the iPh', 'iPhone Dev Team</a></', 'iPhone would be <a hr', 'iPhone with the help ', 'iPhone 5S model, a gr', 'iPhone 3G</a> shown w', 'iPhone is activated.<', 'iPhone was initially ', 'iPhone carriers in th', 'iPhone may be used on', 'iPhone is compatible ', "iPhone 3G\\'s worldwid", 'iPhone without a cont', 'iPhone units is often', 'iPhone since its intr', 'iPhone 5.<sup id="cit', 'iPhone owners.<sup id', 'iPhone are available ', 'iPhone devices, both ', 'iPhone unlocked for f', 'iPhone was officially', 'iPhone is a trademark', 'iPhone brand.<sup id=', 'iPhone and that it ma', 'iPhone 3GS Hardware E', 'iPhone 4 Teardown \\xe', "iPhone 4S\\' A5 CPU at", 'iPhone 4"</a>. <i><a ', 'iPhone 7 &amp; 7 Plus', 'iPhone 5 \\xe2\\x80\\x93', 'iPhone Delivers Up to', 'iPhone 3G S Oleophobi', 'iPhone Secrets and iP', 'iPhone design win"</a', 'iPhone 3GS Hardware E', 'iPhone 3G S Specs"</a', 'iPhone 6s and iPhone ', 'iPhone Blew Up the Wi', 'iPhone secrets"</a>. ', 'iPhone Blew Up the Wi', 'iPhone carrier in US,', 'iPhone met world, 7 y', 'iPhone accessories.</', 'iPhone 3G Country Ava', 'iPhone 3G Coming to c', 'iPhone 3G Price Decre', 'iPhone Users Watch Mo', 'iPhone 3G issues"</a>', 'iPhone 4 Antennagate ', 'iPhone snagged 4.5% o', 'iPhone mobile ad impr', 'iPhone 4S Pre-Orders ', 'iPhone 4S"</a>. CNN<s', 'iPhone Average Sellin', 'iPhone 4S Cracked Ope', 'iPhone manufacturing ', 'iPhone 5S Release Dat', 'iPhone And iPad Scree', 'iPhone 6 and iPhone 6', 'iPhone 7 and 7 Plus a', 'iPhone X"</a>. <i>App', 'iPhone Xs and iPhone ', 'iPhone XR"</a>. <i>Ap', 'iPhone September 10"<', 'iPhone 11"</a>. <i>Ap', 'iPhone 11 is $50 chea', 'iPhone 11 Pro and iPh', 'iPhone 3G sales surpa', 'iPhone sales per quar', 'iPhone Sold, Jobs Bla', 'iPhone in Canada.</sp', 'iPhone Wins Phone Pop', 'iPhone a nightmare fo', 'iPhone Actually Hurts', 'iPhone Is Now Worth M', 'iPhone killer? | FP T', 'iPhone top smartphone', 'iPhone Brand Outshine', 'iPhone 5 Becomes Best', 'iPhone 4S 2nd \\xe2\\x8', 'iPhone Trade-In Progr', 'iPhone 5s And 5c Laun', 'iPhone Production"</a', 'iPhone 5s And iPhone ', 'iPhone 5 Last Year"</', 'iPhone sales"</a>. <i', 'iPhone Upgrade Progra', 'iPhone X starts at $9', 'iPhone to succeed"</a', 'iPhone should focus m', 'iPhone than men"</a>.', 'iPhone 6S orders in 2', 'iPhone X \\xe2\\x80\\x93', 'iPhone Works"</a>. <i', 'iPhone Frequently Ask', 'iPhone FAQs list, Par', 'iPhone 3G S Oleophobi', 'iPhone X: new Apple s', 'iPhone with Software ', 'iPhone does not use t', 'iPhone XR have 3D Tou', 'iPhone FAQ"</a>. <i>w', "iPhone if it\\'s not w", 'iPhone So Cool"</a>. ', 'iPhone 3.0 improvemen', 'iPhone 7 and iPhone 8', 'iPhone 6 Barometer Se', 'iPhone 4&#160;\\xe2\\x8', 'iPhone review"</a>. <', 'iPhone 7 \\xe2\\x80\\x93', 'iPhone headsets"</a>.', 'iPhone X, iPhone 8, o', 'iPhone 8 Plus"</a>. A', 'iPhone 3G"</a>. <i><a', 'iPhone 3G Review"</a>', 'iPhone 3G Reviews: Mo', 'iPhone 3G"</a>. <i><a', 'iPhone wins J.D. Powe', 'iPhone Service Freque', 'iPhone click before C', 'iPhone 3G Battery Is ', 'iPhone X Teardown"</a', 'iPhone battery replac', 'iPhone 3Gs&#160;\\xe2\\', 'iPhone 4&#160;\\xe2\\x8', 'iPhone 4 and iOS 4.1:', 'iPhone 5 Features"</a', 'iPhone 5 Camera Probl', 'iPhone 5"</a>. <i><a ', 'iPhone 4S</a>, by <i>', 'iPhone 8 Plus \\xe2\\x8', 'iPhone X \\xe2\\x80\\x93', 'iPhone X TrueDepth Ca', 'iPhone Atlas. Septemb', 'iPhone 4S, iOS 5 &amp', 'iPhone 5"</a> (Press ', 'iPhone 5s"</a> (Press', 'iPhone SE Storage Cap', 'iPhone Hacks</i><span', 'iPhone 7 storage size', "iPhone 3G\\'s New SIM ", 'iPhone 4&#160;\\xe2\\x8', 'iPhone 4S Internation', 'iPhone 4S"</a>. ZDNet', 'iPhone and iPod: Liqu', 'iPhone 3G Dock"</a>. ', 'iPhone 6"</a>. <i><a ', "iPhone 7: Apple\\'s Ta", 'iPhone OS 4 renamed i', 'iPhone and iPad, here', 'iPhone Applications"<', 'iPhone 4&#160;\\xe2\\x8', 'iPhone 43"</a><span c', 'iPhone voice dialers"', 'iPhone 3G carriers, A', 'iPhone 3G Runs Fast H', 'iPhone 3GS offers spe', 'iPhone Is a Breakthro', 'iPhone is the first s', 'iPhone (yet)"</a>. Th', 'iPhone OS 2.0 will in', 'iPhone 2.2 update"</a', 'iPhone usage shocks s', 'iPhone Data Booms at ', 'iPhone Goes to China ', "iPhone Can\\'t Handle ", "iPhone 6\\'s Wi-Fi Cal", 'iPhone Has a Keyboard', 'iPhone \\xe2\\x80\\x93 T', 'iPhone to support Exc', 'iPhone 3G"</a> (Press', 'iPhone 2.0 software w', 'iPhone customers</q><', 'iPhone \\xe2\\x80\\x93 F', 'iPhone 1.1.3"</a>. <i', 'iPhone MMS launch for', 'iPhone to Support Thi', 'iPhone SDK press conf', 'iPhone sales"</a>. <i', 'iPhone Tethering, Kil', 'iPhone Coders"</a>. g', 'iPhone Matches Most o', 'iPhone met world, 7 y', 'iPhone Changed the Wo', 'iPhone changed phones', 'iPhone 4S was a game-', 'iPhone 6S Review"</a>', 'iPhone Adoption In Bu', 'iPhone hearing aids"<', 'iPhone hearing aids"<', 'iPhone News - Newsroo', 'iPhone Lawsuits"</a>.', 'iPhone trademark chal', 'iPhone trademarks wor', "iPhone suit \\'minor s", 'iPhone Trademark"</a>', 'iPhone Tracks Your Ev', 'iPhone tracking resea', 'iPhone Tracking "Disc', 'iPhone sends your loc', 'iPhone keeps record o', 'iPhone Tracker"</a>. ', 'iPhone (Consolidated.', "iPhone exposing \\'sta", 'iPhone Knows Exactly ', 'iPhone Locks Out N.S.', 'iPhone Crypto Locked ', 'iPhone encryption cas', 'iPhone unlocker devic', 'iPhone murder the Web', 'iPhone can only be ch', 'iPhone apps store. Or', 'iPhone Hacks Void You', 'iPhone Alley</i>. Arc', 'iPhone hackers look t', 'iPhone Independence D', 'iPhone 3G&#160;\\xe2\\x', 'iPhone Users Plagued ', 'iPhone 3G"</a>. Apple', 'iPhone 3G"</a>. Apple', 'iPhone jailbreak for ', 'iPhone jailbreaking v', 'iPhone virus</a>, Bri', 'iPhone owners at risk', 'iPhone 1.1.1, iPod To', 'iPhone 4 jailbreak hi', 'iPhone Dev Team (upda', 'iPhone 3G launch, con', 'iPhone SIM-free for \\', 'iPhone overview</a> f', 'iPhone overview"</a>.', "iPhone 5 won\\'t be \\'", 'iPhone 4 and iPhone 3', 'iPhone 3G &amp; iPhon', 'iPhone Brand Name In ', 'iPhone Trademark"</a>', 'iPhone (English: <i>A', 'iPhone brand</i>)"</a', 'iPhone vs. MyPhone: A', 'iPhone at Macworld 20', 'iPhone bill">300-page', 'iPhone history</a></l', 'iPhone Stereo Headset', 'iPhone \\xe2\\x80\\x93 L']
```

**Any ideas? 
Thank you!**

Comment: Also note that there is a specific `wikipedia` python package, see [here](https://pypi.org/project/wikipedia/). This might be saving you a lot of trouble of parsing through the HTML content. As this is not a direct answer, I'll leave it as a comment for your consideration ;-)

Comment: @dennlinger Thank you. I'll learn and try to use this wikipedia module for future projects!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly the best approach would be **web scraping**, most likely using Beautiful Soup for parsing the HTML. The advantage here is that instead of searching for 'Iphone XXXX' everywhere on the page, you can first parse the whole document in search for the interesting parts. On the [wikipedia page you mentioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone#Models) we can see that the models are listed in two sections: 'Current devices' and 'Past devices'. We can get to this lists via some fancy css-selectors.

```py
import re
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone#Models'

req = urllib.request.Request(url)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

resp_data = resp.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp_data, 'lxml') # you need to get this parser via pip, but it's better than the default one

pattern = re.compile(r'^(iPhone ?.*) \(')
devices = [pattern.match(x.get_text()).group(1) for x in soup.select('h3 ~ div ul > li') if pattern.match(x.get_text())]
print(devices)
```

The logic here is to get all the elements of the lists that are sibling to the `<h3>` headers and match their text to the name 'iPhone XXXX'. I hope this helps.